# Copy files to Docker container using Dockerode without archiving the files

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerode

I am able to copy files to docker container by archiving the files.

```
        var dockerode = require('dockerode');
        var docker = new dockerode();
        var dockrContainer = docker.getContainer(containername);
        dockrContainer.putArchive(srcpath, {path: destpath});
```

The problem is that if I have an archived file in my code repository then my company security scan gives violation. Using dockerode, is it possible to copy multiple files of a directory into docker container without archiving them?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode

Comment: better commit the files directly in code repo and before executing this code try to create a zip file from the files using javascript or nodejs or grunt